# How to set foreign key value to Null when deleting a child record EF Core

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core, ef-code-first

I am quite new to Entity Framework and I have an API that can delete records from a SQL Server database, I have the child table `ResidenceType` and can delete a row using the ID, I have the parent table `PropertyGroups` with a foreign key `ResidenceTypeId`. Is there a way I can set the foreign key's value to `NULL` when I delete a row in `ResidenceType` that is linked?

[image: Residence Type Table]

[image: Residence Type Data]

[image: Property Groups Table]

[image: Property Groups Data]

So the behaviour I need is that if I delete ID 1 from the `ResidenceType` table, I need EF Core to set the `ResidenceTypeId` column in `PropertyGroups` to `NULL` (or empty). I have tried overriding the `OnModelCreating` method in my `DataContext` class but not having much luck, any advice or help would be appreciated.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Turns out I had set everything up correctly I just needed to add the Include clause in the delete method.

```
var residenceType = await _context.ResidenceTypes.Include(p => p.PropertyGroups).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.PropertyGroupName == name);
```

Adding this sets the relevant Id column to null, thanks to the people that tried to help.

Answer (score 0):

In Dbcontext class set OnDelete

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Land>()
            .HasOne(l => l.Building)
            .WithMany(b => b.Lands)
            .HasForeignKey(l => l.BuildingId)
            .OnDelete(Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Metadata.DeleteBehavior.SetNull);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure, if not already, that FK_PropertyGroups_ResidenceTypes_ResidenceTypeId allows NULL, and afterwards when deleting ResidenceType, you’ll just need to issue update, prior to SaveChanges you could foreach every PropertyGroup to update the value of FK to null...I think that would work...but were you looking for a solution how to do the change or how that behavior would be allowed so making sure the FK allows nulls in which case the previous solution is the answer.